# How to do twoside with a macro in the mid of document applying to whole document

Tags: geometry, double-sided, auxiliary-files

I wrote a package on which depending on how the user invokes a macro, it should change the whole document to a twosided document:

MWE test.sty:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesPackage{test}[2022/06/06 v0.01 test.sty]

% \def\Twoside{\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\@twosidetrue\string\@mparswitchtrue}}
% \InputIfFileExists{\jobname.aux}{}\relax

\def\Twoside{\immediate\write\auxoutii{\string\@twosidetrue\string\@mparswitchtrue}}
\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.aux2}{}\relax
\newwrite\auxoutii
\immediate\openout\auxoutii=\jobname.aux2
\AtEndDocument{\immediate\closeout\auxoutii}

\endinput
```

MWE test.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{test}
% \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[hmargin={0cm,2cm}]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\Twoside
first page \cleardoublepage third page \clearpage fourth page
\end{document}
```

In this simplified MWE I wrote this `\Twoside` macro changes the document to a twosided document. It works but if `geometry` is being loaded before the test package, it won't work. And I don't like writing to a second aux file only to write that line. It is possible to handle this on the main aux file?

Uncommenting the commented lines on the `.sty` file and commenting the following five lines it works but fails when `babel` is loaded. Why this? Why the line with `\InputIfFileExists` is needed to manage executing the line written to the main aux file?

Edited:

A more real life MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{elzcards}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin={2cm,0cm}]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\IndexCard{\vfill\mbox{}\hfill - \CurrentIC{} - front side\hfill\mbox{}\vfill}
\IndexCard{\vfill\mbox{}\hfill - \CurrentIC{} - front side\hfill\mbox{}\vfill}
\IndexCard{\vfill\mbox{}\hfill - \CurrentIC{} - front side\hfill\mbox{}\vfill}[\vfill\mbox{}\hfill - \CurrentIC{} - back side\hfill\mbox{}\vfill]
\IndexCard{\vfill\mbox{}\hfill - \CurrentIC{} - front side\hfill\mbox{}\vfill}
\IndexCard{\vfill\mbox{}\hfill - \CurrentIC{} - front side\hfill\mbox{}\vfill}
\MakeIC
\end{document}
```

In the real life example, each `\IndexCard` call adds a card to a 'stack'. Only the third index card has a reverse side (the second argument of `\IndexCard` with square brackets is the presence of the back side). When a card is defined with back side, the document should change as it were defined as a `twoside`d document. It works but with some issues.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the purpose? Why should the user learn to use a new command instead of the standard option `twoside`? Beside this: don't load the aux-file manually. That is the job of latex.

Comment: this seems to be the wrong approach, a more standard mechanism would be to use `twoside`  throughout, but set the frontmatter with a page style in which odd and even page headings were the same

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. I wrote this minimalistic macro only for MWE purposes; that's not the real situation. Obviously I don't want the user issuing a command to change a behavior always handled by an option class. The real situation is that in my package to write business/index cards, the user adds all cards one by one, but if at least one card has back side, the whole document should behave automatically as a `twoside`d document. Sure, the aux-file shouldn't be loaded manually, but if I don't load it manually, these both conditionals remains as they were not changed to true...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the purpose that `twoside` behavior be changed in the middle of the document but applying to the whole document. The `\Twoside` option on the MWE is a simplified version of the real problem.

Comment: well your code will explode if you load the aux in the wrong place. So don't do it. Beside this: If you use geometry you should use it throughout and not set some options manually.  So try to write `\geometry{twoside}` to the aux.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes, sure. I know I'm parsing the aux-file from the wrong place... The code will explode in some circumstances. I edited the question!

Comment: Hello @DavidCarlisle or UlrikeFischer. Any advice on this? I edited the original post showing the real situation. Thnx!